# whay backaward slash in the parameter element of the javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was inspecting [this site](http://ipsos.com.au/) in firebug. Inside the third `<script/>` tag in the `head` section of the  page , I found an object variable declared in the following way ( truncated here however by me) :

```
var EM={
"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/ipsos.com.au\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php",

"bookingajaxurl":"http:\/\/ipsos.com.au\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php",

"locationajaxurl":"http:\/\/ipsos.com.au\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php?action=locations_search",

"firstDay":"1","locale":"en"};
```

The utility of the variable is unknown to me. What struck me is the 3 urls presented there. Why are the backward slashes present there? Couldn't it be something like :

"ajaxurl" : **"http://ipsos.com.au/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"**

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a script element there are various character sequences (depending on the version of HTML) that will terminate the element. `</script>` will always do this.

`<\/script>` will not.

Escaping `/` characters will not change the meaning of the JS, but will prevent any such HTML from ending the script.

Comment: but why \/\/ in url? instead of http://? is there any specific reason for that? i do aware of escaping character.

Comment: @shreedhar — Because it is a simple escape over all `/`s to prevent `</script>` from appearing.

Comment: @Quentin, your answer seems to be difficult to understand. Will you be kind enough to explain it from the ground up ? Or any online resource to refer?

Comment: `</` starts an end tag. `<\/` does not start an end tag. Escaping all `/` will stop `</` from appearing.

Comment: @Quentin, but the question was about escaping inside the url parameter. How does your answer explain that please?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed — The tool generating the object literal doesn't care that it is a URL. Escaping **all** `/` will stop `</` from appearing, so it does.

Comment: @Quentin, '..tool generating the object literal ..' - so you mean , the coder did not put the backslashes manually, rather those were added by some plugin etc? Still trying to understand your answer .

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed What if the url was: `"http://example.com/</script>/"`? You'd have a serious bug.  So it's just easier to over-escape the urls.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed — Yes. Large chunks of object literals are often generated programatically.

Comment: @Quentin, in what way? can you shed a bit light on that ? for more clarity, what would be the problem if no backslashes were used?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed — The problem is that the data might include the sequence `</script>` which would **terminate the script element** in the middle of a string literal.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed — In the "Here is some data I got out of my database, now I shall dump it into a JavaScript object literal and send it to a web browser so that the data is available to JS" sense (for example)

Comment: let me understand in my own way ... An URL has multiple parts - each starting after a forward slash. Those parts are not any variable to contain any data. So why to escape ?

Comment: @Quentin,   let me understand in my own way ... An URL has multiple parts - each starting after a forward slash. Those parts are not any variable to contain any data. So why to escape ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed — Forget about the data being URLs. That doesn't matter. They are strings. Those strings **are** variables in the server side script that is generating the JavaScript. They JavaScript object literal is not hand crafted (or if it is, then someone is being a cargo cultist, but that doesn't detract from the reason the escapes are there in general).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17482/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-quentin)

Comment: @Scott Rippey yeah that's what Ive mentioned in the answer before

Comment: @Quentin, things if I could get to know first would help me understand more quickly: 1)escaping forward slashes is necessary in case of the presence of the character sequence - `</script>` before the actually ending </script> tag to prevent the script considering the former one as the ending tag . 2) escaping the backslashes was not necessary here if the coder was well aware of the `non-disturbing nature` of the url parts. 3)  A tool might have been used to escape even the forward slashes of the whole javascript snippet. Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 2):

The `\/\/` is to avoid the below scenario:

when the url looks something similar to `"ajaxurl" : "http://google.com/search?q=</script>"`


Try copy paste the url in browsers address bar. This is handled correctly. Otherwise, You might end up getting script errors and page might not work as you've expected.


imagine DOM manipulators replacing the value as it is in the src attribute of the script tag and then the javascript engine reporting multiple errors because that particular script referenced might not get loaded due to incorrectly defined src value

Hope this helps.

Life would be hectic without these lil things

Comment: pasted the url and google made a search for the string </script>.. No problem occured. explain please

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed — Because the URL is not the problem. The problem, as I said in my answer, is the sequence of characters `</script>` inside a script element in an HTML document.

Comment: Still not clear to me. I asked Quentin questions. To you, my question is : if the backslashes were not used, what would be the problems? Answer with specific example would be very helpful

Comment: "imagine DOM manipulators replacing the value as it is in the src attribute of the script tag and then the javascript engine reporting multiple errors" — They wouldn't. The problem is when `</script>` appears inside a script element, not inside a `src` attribute.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed the URL will be escaped and then processed. That's why we don't have any issues with the `</script>` being placed inside an address

Comment: @Quentin I've edited the answer hope this matches the context

Answer (score 0):

It is used to escape the characters..

The backslash () can be used to insert apostrophes, new lines, quotes, and other special characters into a string.

```
var str = " Hello "World" !! ";
alert(str)
```

This won't work..

You have to escape them first

```
var str = " Hello \"World\" !! ";
alert(str) ; \\ This works
```

In terms of Javascript `/ and <\/` are identical inside a string. As far as HTML is concerned `</` starts an end tag but `<\/` does not.

Comment: why to escape? details please

Comment: The question is about escaping `/` characters, not `"` characters.